# VB if base class implements interface, does the derived class also need to implement?

Tags: vb.net, oop

I was analyzing a code. There we have a base class (not abstract) implementing an interface. Then we have a derived class of the base class which also implements the interface.
Interface:

```
Public Interface MainInterface

    Function getMetaThreads(ByVal ThreadCount As Integer) As String()
    Property Name() As String
    Property TargetDirectory() As String
    Property TimeOut() As Long
    ReadOnly Property ExecutableAssembly() As String
    ReadOnly Property IsVersionValid() As Boolean

End Interface
```

Base class:

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Implements MainInterface

    Public Sub print() 
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass printing")
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property ExecutableAssembly As String Implements MainInterface.ExecutableAssembly
        ...
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsVersionValid As Boolean Implements MainInterface.IsVersionValid
        ...
    End Property
    Protected strName As String = ""
    Protected strTargetDirectory As String = ""
    Protected lngTimeout As Long = 0

    Public Property Name As String Implements MainInterface.Name
        ...
    End Property

    Public Property TargetDirectory As String Implements MainInterface.TargetDirectory
        ...
    End Property

    Public Property TimeOut As Long Implements MainInterface.TimeOut
        ...
    End Property

    Public Function getMetaThreads(ThreadCount As Integer) As String() Implements MainInterface.getMetaThreads
        ...
    End Function
    Public  Overridable Function  myOwnFunc() As String
       Return ""
    End Function
End Class
```

Derived Class:

```
Public Class SubClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Implements MainInterface

    Public Function getMetaThreads(ThreadCount As Integer) As String() Implements MainInterface.getMetaThreads
        Return myOwnFunc()
    End Function

    Overrides Function myOwnFunc() As String()
        Dim l As New List (Of String) 
        l.Add("44")
        l.Add("33")
        return l.ToArray()

    End Function
End Class
```

Does it make sense to implement the interface in the derived class again? Is there a reason or a case where this becomes necessary? I think that having the base class implement the interface should be enough and implementing it in the interface is redundant.

Comment: It will implement the interface by default.  Specifying it explicitly is just for clarity.  Hiding or overriding the methods is optional based on the functionality of the derived class.

Comment: Only if you have a reason to re-implement the interface method.  And then you ought to strongly consider to make the base class method implementation Overridable so you can Override it in the derived class.  That way it doesn't matter which reference the client code uses.